# How to make a single react component which can be used iteratively to display different products. Like an e-commerce website

Tags: reactjs, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to build a book review website, I have a card component which which has elements like book title, author, year, etc and it is used multiple times to show no. of books, but I don't know how to update each copy of card with different book details every time the card is used and the details are downloaded from the server using Axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear with the question that you're asking but I'll take a shot at it. In react, you should have a main component that renders all of the cards (i.e BookReviews). That component should have an internal state, perhaps an array of objects that hold a review. You should fetch that array from Flask when the component mounts and then you should render each card individually.

For example:

```
const BookReview = ({review: {id, name, rating}) => {
   return (
      <div className="card">
          {name}
      </div>
   );
}

const BookReviews = () => {
   const [reviews, setReviews] = React.useState([]);
   
   React.useEffect(() => {
      // fetch reviews using ajax request and call setReviews with result
   })


   return (
      <div className="book-reviews">
      {reviews.map(i => <BookReview key={i.id} review={i} />}
      </div>
   );
}
```

Then in your flask app, have a route to retrieve all of the reviews from the database and return them in a serialized format:

```
@app.route('/reviews')
def book_reviews():
   return jsonify(reviews=[{'id': i.id, 'name': i.name, 'stars': i.stars} for i in BookReview.query.all()]), 200
```